# Android RSA decryption using private key, non-sense result

Tags: java, android, rsa, private-key

I am doing RSA decryption in my Android project, and somehow the result makes non-sense. I am showing my code here:

```
private static final int MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK = 256;


private static RSAPrivateKey loadPrivateKey(InputStream in) throws Exception {
    RSAPrivateKey priKey;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String readLine = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (readLine.charAt(0) == '-') {
                continue;
            } else {
                sb.append(readLine);
                sb.append('\r');
            }
        }
        byte[] priKeyData = Base64.decode(new String(sb), Base64.NO_WRAP);



        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec= new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(priKeyData);
        KeyFactory keyFactory= KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA",new BouncyCastleProvider());
        priKey= (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception("error reading the key");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new Exception("inputstream is null");
    }
    return priKey;
}


/**
 * decrypt with a private key
 *
 * @param privateKey
 * @param cipherData
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static byte[] decrypt(RSAPrivateKey privateKey, byte[] cipherData) throws Exception {
    if (privateKey == null) {
        throw new Exception("key is null");
    }
    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        int inputLen = cipherData.length;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int offSet = 0;
        byte[] cache;
        int i = 0;
        while (inputLen - offSet > 0) {
            if (inputLen - offSet > MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK) {
                cache = cipher.doFinal(cipherData, offSet, MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK);
            } else {
                cache = cipher.doFinal(cipherData, offSet, inputLen - offSet);
            }
            out.write(cache, 0, cache.length);
            i++;
            offSet = i * MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK;
        }
        byte[] decryptedData = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();
        return decryptedData;

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new Exception("no such algorithm");
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new Exception("InvalidKeyException");
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        throw new Exception("IllegalBlockSizeException");
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        throw new Exception("BadPaddingException");
    }
}

public static String RSADecrypt(Context context, String KeyFileNameInAssetFolder, byte[] content) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().getAssets().open(KeyFileNameInAssetFolder);
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = loadPrivateKey(inputStream);
        byte[] b = decrypt(privateKey, content);
        return new String(b,"utf-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "error";
}
```

and I am calling with this statement:

```
String result = RSAUtils.RSADecrypt(getApplicationContext(), Constant.PRIVATE_KEY_PKCS8_FILE_NAME,Base64.decode(qrcode_result,Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

And this is the private key:

```
> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and this is the string I tried to decrypt:

```
JRhdX3DLGbMVcxN6jV3697yUkfZUBfz/ee6P8pGlgHFnOo5OWgXH0fc10Ps4li3UKkyVqo1+iz10/zzhjVTbSKC5Fai6dLnQgrFVz6lOqOeR83+x4ezyF75kORdgAyEp5MiW0LHsK13ryYEqZ1GHiZdJ6E54nbLZsZGKJJkRZ2OVQW9hovqBQXAP3M8dGk1liruiY+xAHfKkeS73m+IPYPTNGQT+y5IDACoq8dLUvV4nw76p2ZUfyYFgoYOir9KBN2SbfcndR71DZUPWdRnZoDLNFCfvMjC2Ui27j3CxcQLzJSt4K4K+kmU6n5t8Xb6YyGb2j+5pduXcnZMgc5cjsm6NBIXUv+DQzXeRo61vHrXKWeamJ+Whl0RnA9HjIl6medxfE64xHgF+aD6lqbQcwWwHWm/s3f5XkS0xP21bYuOt8mgmHC90qhJNRGKmTGgyxxls/18aV4eZEIRUg82wCIXavvQGLA3hk5UWl4YkrpaGYh+SX1t3yfi+wQ8f30lQBrKl4A0iKk4WHKNCka6nd3sc8bDwD42cvQiFSPCp7m4DRtXy1CRzNmRG7FmSK8SgkQOWSWE+6KRKat88j0Nw+Rg6U1YaMBofJOLKfIswLHgW44Bpf2c0eynJEZdLi94oOh7lkTHcaqwBiO1MWg9eiYT/j7qXCPjoi9q3PzPhxoA=
```

and the decryption result is like this:

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfuaP.png)

Comment: result is like        "���#���U�)�3�0ͧ%�K��>\5[�H�D�4��I��dE%/�щY�[��,tu�L&��'@��b�j���W��a�i~�l�����1��������z��̌��|Cq��"

Comment: You need to know *how* it was encrypted before you attempt to decrypt it, otherwise you're wasting your time. Your RSA is 256 bytes in length, but the data your trying to decrypt in 512 bytes, so that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You may need to base64 decode the encrypted string before trying to run java classes on it, since java classes typically operate on byte streams and not base64 strings.

Comment: As James already pointed out the data you have encrypted is too large for the used key. RSA can only be used for encrypting small parts of data (smaller than the RSA key size). Hence the decryption will never work as the encryption already has screwed up the data.

Comment: @konsolas I did base64 decode when calling the decrypt method, as it shows in my calling statement

Comment: @Robert I 64decoded the data to make it smaller before decryption

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. You'll need to take action on James K Polk's comment then. The code looks accurate, so the only possibility seems to be a mismatch with the input ciphertext.

Comment: @Adam Chen Even if you decode the base64 data the simple fact is that it is too much data (max is ~250 bytes). If you need to encrypt larger data you should use hybrid encryption (encrypt data with random AES key and then encrypt the AES key with RSA).